Is $f_{n}(x) = \frac{\sigma_{n+1}(x)/\sigma_{n}(x)}{\sigma_{n}(x)/\sigma_{n-1}(x)}$ unbounded for all $n$?
Take, for instance, the function $f_{1}(x) = \frac{\sigma_2(x)/\sigma_1(x)}{\sigma_1(x)/\sigma_0(x)}$. The sequence of positive integers $k$ for whom $f_1(k)$ is greater than all previous integers, begins
$${2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14, 22, 26, 34, 38, 46, 58, 62, 74, 82, 86, 94, 106, 118, 122, 134, 142, 146, 158, 166, 178, 194, 202, 206, 214, 218, 226, 238, 242, 286, 338, 374, 418, 442, 494, 598, 646, 754, 782, 874, 986, 1054, 1102, 1178, 1334...}$$
...the largest $f_{1}(k)$-value of which is roughly $2.8$. The largest $f_1(k)$-value for $k < 1000000$ is roughly $14.2$.
If we try $n = 2$, giving us $f_{2}(x) = \frac{\sigma_{3}(x)/\sigma_{2}(x)}{\sigma_{2}(x)/\sigma_{1}(x)}$, we get a much more sporadic sequence: the sequence of positive integers $k$ for whom $f_2(k)$ is greater than all previous integers begins
$$2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14, 16, 20, 28, 36, 40, 56, 70, 112, 140, 210, 224, 280, 504, 560, 770, 1120, 1680, 2240, 2520, 5040, 6160, 10010, 10080, 12320, 15120, 24640, 25200, 27720, 50050, 50400, 55440, 110880, 160160, 166320, 277200, 332640, 554400, 665280, 720720...$$
... the largest $f_2(k)$-value of which is roughly $1.9$.
Larger values of $n$ reveal much lower "greatest values" of $f_n(k)$ for higher $k$.
Now define a new function $g_n(k)$ as "the largest value of $f_n(j)$ for $0 < j \le k$ and $j \in \mathbb{Z}$". My question is as follows:

Is $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} g_n(x) = \infty$ for all $n$? If so, how does the growth rate compare to $n$? If not, is the equation satisfied for any $n$? For the $n$ for which the equation is untrue, what is the behavior of the function?


What is $\sigma_n$?

The sum of the divisors of $n$ - see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

$\sigma_k(n)$ is the sum of the $k$-th powers of the divisors of $n$.

The title asks whether a function tends to infinity, while the end of the post asks whether that function is unbounded above; which is intended?

Sorry - unbounded is the idea I was going for - I'll fix the title.

These questions are determined by the behavior of the multiplicative functions on prime powers. Note that
$$
\sigma_n(p^k) = \sum_{j=0}^k p^{jn} = \begin{cases}
k+1, &\text{if } n=0, \\
(p^{n(k+1)}-1)/(p^n-1), &\text{if } n\ge1.
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
f_1(p^k) = \frac{(k+1) (p-1) (p^{k+1}+1)}{(p+1) (p^{k+1}-1)} = (k+1)(1+O(p^{-1})),
$$
which is unbounded even for a single prime $p$ as $k\to\infty$. Next,
$$
f_2(p^k) = \frac{(p+1)^2 (p^{k+1}+p^{2 k+2}+1)}{(p^2+p+1)
   (p^{k+1}+1)^2} = \biggl( 1 - \frac1p \biggr)^{-1} \bigl( 1 + O(p^{-2}) \bigr);
$$
since $\prod_p \bigl( 1 + O(p^{-2}) \bigr)$ converges, we conclude that
$$
f_2(m) \asymp \prod_{p\mid m} \biggl( 1 - \frac1p \biggr)^{-1} = \frac m{\phi(m)},
$$
which is also unbounded.
However, for $n\ge3$,
$$
f_n(p^k) = \frac{(p^n-1)^2 ((p^{k+1})^{n-1}-1)
   ((p^{k+1})^{n+1}-1)}{(p^{n-1}-1)
   (p^{n+1}-1) ((p^{k+1})^n-1)^2} = 1 + O(p^{-2}),
$$
and so $f_n(m)$ is bounded uniformly in $m$ for all $n\ge3$.

Cool, thanks! Appreciate the help.
